# Extra space in list of author names

Tags: spacing, bibtex, natbib, revtex

When an entry in my bibliography has more than two authors then for some reason what looks like an extra space appears in the list of names,
i.e.
`A. One, A. Two,  and A. Three` rather than
`A. One, A. Two, and A. Three` as I believe it should be.

I'm using revtex, and editing in ShareLatex. This is what I'm seeing in the pdf generated from the below MWE, where you can see the extra space in reference [3]:
[image: extraspace]

MWE TeX:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum~\cite{article1,article2,article3}.

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{name}

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@article{article1,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {1},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    author = {One, Author},
    year = {2000}}

@article{article2,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {1},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    author = {One, Author and Two, Author},
    year = {2000}}

@article{article3,
    title = {Title},
    volume = {1},
    journal = {Journal Title},
    author = {One, Author and Two, Author and Three, Author},
    year = {2000}}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: This appears to be caused by a space being added by both the `and` and `,` clauses within the `format.names` function of [`apsrev4-1.bst`](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/bibtex/bst/revtex/apsrev4-1.bst).

Comment: This does indeed look like a bug, you should contact the maintainers at https://journals.aps.org/revtex

Comment: @CobyViner That seems to be it. Do you have a solution to the problem and want to type up an answer?

Comment: @moewe Unfortunately not. I looked into it and determined it would take me well over an hour to fix. Perhaps someone with greater expertise at that stack programming language could try to do so.

Comment: @CobyViner OK, I have typed up a quick answer.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in version 4-2

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the `.bst` file, contact the maintainer of the REVTeX package, https://journals.aps.org/revtex.

The problem is that the `.bst` file inserts spaces as `\` instead of   in the two functions `format.names` and `format.names.ed`. In these cases two consecutive spaces are not run into one as normally. Incidentally, the style gets it right in the `format.full.names` function.

To fix this you must modify the `.bst` directly. If you submit to a journal that could be problematic depending on their workflow.

1. Locate `apsrev4-1.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich apsrev4-1.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/bibtex/bst/revtex/apsrev4-1.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-inst-wlcf.html
3. Rename the file to `apsrev4-1-nospace.bst` (the license of `apsrev4-1.bst` strongly encourages you to change the name if you modify the file)
4. Open the file and find the function `FUNCTION {format.names}` (in my version ll. 1541-1579) and replace the entire block with

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.names}
   { 'bibinfo :=
     duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ "" } {
       duplicate$ num.names$
       duplicate$ 'numnames :=
       'namesleft :=
       's :=
       #1 'nameptr :=
       ""
         { namesleft #0 > }
         {
         format.names.morfont
           bibinfo bibinfo.check
           type$ "presentation" =
             'check.speaker
             'skip$
           if$
           't :=
           nameptr #1 > not
             {
               t *
             } {
               namesleft #1 >
                 {
                   names.punctuate
                   t *
                 } {
                   s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                     { 't := }
                     { pop$ }
                   if$
                   numnames #2 >
                     { "," * }
                     'skip$
                   if$
                   t "others" =
                     {
                       " " *
                       bbl.etal
                       emphasize
                       *
                     } {
                       bbl.and
                       space.word *
                       t *
                     }
                   if$
                 }
               if$
             }
           if$
           nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
           namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
         }
       while$
     } if$
   }
   ```

   The only change is in line 1573 (the line after `numnames #2 >`) where we replaced `'names.punctuate` with `{ "," * }`. This only inserts a comma and not a comma and space.
5. Do the same for `FUNCTION {format.names.ed}` (ll. 1695-1746). It should be replaced with

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
   {
     control.editor #0 > {
       format.names
     } {
       'bibinfo :=
       duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
       's :=
       "" 't :=
       #1 'nameptr :=
       s num.names$ 'numnames :=
       numnames 'namesleft :=
         { namesleft #0 > }
         {
          format.names.ed.morfont
           bibinfo bibinfo.check
           't :=
           nameptr #1 >
             {
               namesleft #1 >
                 {
                   names.punctuate
                   t *
                 }{
                   s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                     { 't := }
                     { pop$ }
                   if$
                   numnames #2 >
                     { "," * }
                     'skip$
                   if$
                   t "others" =
                     {
                       " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                     }{
                      bbl.and
                       space.word * t *
                     }
                   if$
                 }
               if$
             }
             't
           if$
           nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
           namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
         }
       while$
       } if$
     } if$
   }
   ```

   Again the change is in the line after `numnames #2 >`, i.e. in line 1724, where `'names.punctuate` was replaced with `{ "," * }`.
6. Add your name and date and explain the modification in the comments at the top of the file.
7. Use `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1-nospace}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` in your document.